# Keeping emacs from splitting the window when openning multiple files

Tags: configuration, emacs

Whenever I open more than one file at the same time with emacs, as in:

```
emacs foo.dat bar.dat
```

The window that opens will be split between the two files (a buffer for each file). I would like to avoid that. Is there a line I can place in my `.emacs` file to keep that from happening? I would like emacs to only open one buffer in the window, no matter how many files I'm loading.

I'm using version 23.1.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code works for me (add into `~/.emacs`):

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda () (delete-other-windows)) t)
```

The `emacs-startup-hook` is run after loading the init file and processing the command line, so all files have been loaded and opened; calling `delete-other-windows` leaves just one of them visible (normally the last one given on the command line).

*Note:* you *might* also need to customize `inhibit-startup-screen` and set it to `t` for the above to work.

Comment: It's unlikely to matter in this case, but you should always use `add-hook` for hooks, rather than manipulate the list directly. In an unrelated note, curiously, if `inhibit-startup-screen` if left off, you get exactly two windows: one for the last file on the command line and one with the startup screen.